# Upgrade Xubuntu 15.04 with a 3.19.0-18-lowlatency kernel

Tags: upgrade, kernel, xubuntu

I use Xubuntu 15.04 with 3.19.0-18-low latency kernel. If I upgrade the system to Xubuntu 15.10 the kernel will be replaced by a generic? (sorry for my poor english)

Comment: did you compile the kernel manually? Or using PPA?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly how the upgrade scripts work with non-default kernels. The kernel will be probably replaced with `generic`.

But that is not a problem. You can replace `generic` kernel with a `lowlatency` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
sudo apt-get remove linux-generic
```

This will replace meta-packages and will install the `lowlatency` kernel. You can also install Synaptic and remove `generic` linux images and headers.

Comment: From a Ubuntu USB or it would kill itself

Comment: What would kill what and why?

Comment: the kernel/OS (duh.)

Comment: The above is a very good answer.   Generally if   have a low-latency kernel then when you upgrade you will generally get only other low-latency kernels.  However if you want to switch either to low-latency or away from it.

Answer (score 0):

The above is a very good answer.   Generally, if you used a package manager to install a low-latency kernel then when you upgrade you will generally get only other low-latency kernels.  However, if you want to switch either to low-latency or away from it the apt install/remove will work fine

sudo apt-get install linux-lowlatency
sudo apt-get remove linux-generic

or if you want to switch away:

sudo apt-get remove linux-lowlatency
sudo apt-get install linux-generic

and then 
apt-get autoremove

to remove the files and menu entry